# List on python: where has the `u` come from?

Tags: python, list

Quick question:

```
disc_list=[] #creating an empty list to put the discs into
    rad = 70
for i in range(5):
    disc_list.append(cmds.polyCylinder( name = 'disc' + str(i), radius = rad, height = 10)[0]) # create discs
    cmds.move(0, 10*i, 0, ('disc' + str(i)))
    rad = rad*0.7 

    print disc_list
```

anyone know why when I print the `disc_list`, this is returned:

```
[u'disc0', u'disc1', u'disc2', u'disc3', u'disc4']
```

where has the `u` come from?

Comment: when i first saw this I had the same question. It just denotes that the string is unicode as sshashank124 states below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `u` simply denotes that it is a `unicode` string. You should not worry about it. When you print it, it will still be the same.

```
for i in disc_list:
    print i

[OUTPUT]
disc0
disc1
disc2
disc3
disc4
```

[**Suggested link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-rstring-flags-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-litte)